# Why won't Google Chrome install on my Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, spyware

I can tell something is wrong with my computer.

A little history: Google Chrome was not running correctly. When i was using facebook, any link on face that ran an ajax javascript function would not work. No error was being thrown, it just wasn't working.

I uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled it. On re-install, a toolbar automatically installed with Chrome. BitTorrentBar. I did not install BitTorrentBar, it installed on it's own. Bad.

When BitTorrentBar was active, then ajax functions on facebook worked. When I deactivated or uninstalled BittorrentBar from Chrome extensions, then ajax stopped working.

I ran scanned the computer with Avast (free version) and SpyBot Search and Destroy (also free). They found nothing wrong.

I uninstalled Chrome using Control Panel and then I went through my file system deleting anything that had "google", "BitTorrent", "chrome", or "conduit". Conduit seems to distribute BitTorrentBar.

After doing all that, I tried to reinstall Chrome. I got this error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at ClickOnceBootStrap.ClickOnceEntry.Main()
```

This error interupts the Chrome install every time! computer scans don't show anything wrong.

So then, I thought this might be a .net framework error. Perhaps I deleted something I wasn't supposed to. So I reinstalled .NET Framework 4 and checked the repair option. I also ran Windows Updates.

When I tried to download Chrome, again I got the same error as listed above.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you checked your system using sfc.exe (System File Checker)?

Comment: I have not. I'll look for that.

Comment: I ran sfc.exe. I just saw a prompt pop up and then almost immediately disappear. I don't think it's doing anything.

Comment: sfc is a command line app. Start cmd.exe and then start it from there.

Comment: I ran `sfc /SCANNOW`. It said that 'Windows Resources Protection did not find any integrity vioolations.

Comment: I tried to install Google Chrome again and I got the same error.

Comment: Not really an answer, but try installing Rockmelt http://www.rockmelt.com/ or SRWare Iron http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron_chrome_vs_iron.php or Comodo Dragon http://www.comodo.com/dragon/intl/en-GB/browserchoice/faq.html

They're all based on Chrome, compatible with Chrome plugins. However, they're bit behind Chrome, as in probably not supporting latest Chrome features.

On the other hand, you can try Chromium http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?path=Win/ (pick the latest folder), the bleeding edge of Chrome, unstable.

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo - I guess I'm more interested in figuring out what's broken than finding an alternative. Thanks for the suggestions though!